# Issue in using the "\n" as a delimiter in java

Tags: java

hi this is my file contents

```
#nadal\r\n#federer\r\n*#djokovic\r\n#murray\r\n
```

i want to use \n as delimiter i want my output as

```
#nadal\r
#federer\r
*#djokovic\r
#murray\r
```

i googled about it but i could not find answer

here is my code written in java

```
    Scanner scan=null;

    scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("//Users//Rakesh//Desktop//input.txt"));

    // initialize the string delimiter
    scan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n;]+"));



    // Printing the delimiter used
    System.out.println("The delimiter use is "+scan.delimiter());

    // Printing the tokenized Stringhashtable
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(scan.next());
    }

    // closing the scanner stream
    scan.close();
```

i am getting output as whole line instead of in new line.Can any one help on this TIA

Comment: Are those newlines in your file, or literal `\r\n`?

Comment: Question says /n, body says \n ?

Comment: If you're using `\r` as part of your delimiter, it's not going to be in your output.

Answer (score 1):

Your program works fine for me, producing one output line for each input line. Except for the detail that, to be the output lines ended in \r, the delimitters must be like this:

```
    scan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\n]+"));
```

(The semicolon delimitter is no use with that input format).